# Screen display issues

Tags: display

I recently installed Ubuntu in my laptop. After rebooting I see fine horizontal lines flickering on the screen whenever the laptop is running on battery. If I plug in AC power then the flickering stops. What could be the reason and how do I solve it?

By the way, I'm using AMD processor and AMD graphics card as hardware.